# Is liquibase using a timestamp to create its temp folders?

Tags: liquibase

We run a *lot* of releases, and because of this we have threaded them, all kicking off at the same time, on the same server.

We've noticed, however, that when multiple releases with liquibase kick off at the same time, to different databases, they invariably fail.

This leads me to wonder how they are stepping on each other. It seems to be time-based, as running these releases individually after they have failed is successful.

Am I right about this? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: I have no clue if liquibase is multi-threadable in the way you describe. I'd say why not but as you've already done this and found out it's not mabye you should add more details to the failure message you get.

Comment: We are currently using Liquibase via Maven, which may be our issue, as it writes out a file in the ~/.m2/repository folder every time it kicks off, and with 3 environments going at once it seems to have contention issues over that file. We are moving to using it via a normal command line execution with the jar, and I'm betting that this will allow the threading.